# Package errors in Java

Tags: java, package

I am trying to get the hang of packages in java and currently I can get the classes to compile but I cannot get the main class to compile. I have JDK 8.0 and notepad++ with the nppexec plugin installed on a flash drive so I can program, compile, and run on pretty much on any windows 7 computer. To compile the code I am using the following script:

```
//save current file
NPP_SAVE 
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
"\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac"  $(FILE_NAME)
```

To run the compiled classes i am using the folling script:

```
//save current file
//NPP_SAVE
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" 
"\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java" -classpath "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

The files are located in "\Workspace\personstest" there are currently on two files Person.java and PersonsTest.java both are located in the same file. A simplified version of person.java:

```
package personstest;
public class Person {
//fields and methods 
}
```

The version of PersonsTest.java:

```
package personstest;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, email, phoneNumber;
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter "+ name + "'s Email: ");
        email = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter "+ name + "'s Phone Number: ");
        phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        Person leo = new Person(name, email, phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(leo);        
    } 
}
```

Like I said the Person.java classes compiles fine  but not the PersonsTest.java. The syntax is correct because if I comment out the the lines containing the package personstest; line they both compile correctly and I am able to run the program. I believe the issue is the command lines that I used to execute need to be modified but i am not familiar with that type of syntax. The follow errors occur when i compile the main class:

```
PersonsTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Person leo = new Person(name, email, phoneNumber);
    ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonsTest
PersonsTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Person leo = new Person(name, email, phoneNumber);
                     ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonsTest
2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely advise you to start using a IDE like Eclipse so that these type of errors can be caught in the editor itself.

Hope some of these leads help:

When a Java program is being compiled the compiler creates a list of all the identifiers in use. If it can't find what an identifier refers to (e.g., there is no declaration statement for a variable) it cannot complete the compilation. This is what the cannot find symbol error message is saying, it doesn't have enough information to piece together what the Java code wants to execute.

Possible Causes:

1) trying to use a variable without declaring it.

2) misspelling a class or method name (remember, Java is case sensitive).

3) the parameters used do not match a method's signature.

4) the packaged class has not being referenced correctly using an import declaration.